# Swift Extract textFieldButton.text From array

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

I can extract each individual value of an array to fill my textfield like this

```
var animal: [String] = ["Leo", "Coyote", "bear", "Cheetah"]
textFieldButton.text = "\(animal[index])"
```

I'm trying to do the same for an array stored in a plist file ... 
I extract the array

```
var Name: AnyObject! = data?.valueForKey("NomeScenario")
```

but when I try to

```
textFieldButton.text = "\(Name[index])"
```

my plist file is

```
<dict>
<key>NomeScenario</key>
<string>[ee, rr]</string>
<key>NumeroScenario</key>
<string>2</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I get an SourcesKit service error

Answer (score 0):

You can not get element from `AnyObject` as it is not array.You need to cast it to array

```
   var Name:[String] = data!.valueForKey("NomeScenario") as [String]
   textFieldButton.text = "\(Name[index])"
```

Edit: In your `plist` you are storing `String` not array

```
   var Name:String = data!.valueForKey("NomeScenario") as String
   textFieldButton.text = "\(Name)"   // print [ee,rr]
```

You should set array in `plist` if you want to work with array

```
yourPlistVar.setValue(["ee","rr"], forKey: "NomeScenario")
```

than write the plist

Edit change the code to

```
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:.Default, handler: {
        (UIAlertAction) in
        self.specs.append(self.newSpecificationTitleTextField!.text)

        //remove the string here
        data?.setValue(self.specs, forKey: "NomeScenario")
        data?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true) //Write data to file permanently

    }))
```

Comment: check if you are getting `data` `nil` or are you getting proper `Name` as string array.Without knowing what is in Plist hard to tell.

Comment: but in my plist there is a array = [xx, vv]

Comment: can you post `plist` as XML.Open in `textEditor`

Comment: `[ee, rr]` this is string not array

Comment: I have posted as I will save my plist fron ti UialertController

Answer (score 0):

yes , but i used a AlertController for upload my plist like this

```
  var newSpecificationTitleTextField: UITextField?
  var specs : [String] = []

  var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
  alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in
        self.newSpecificationTitleTextField = textField
    }
  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:.Default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
        self.specs.append(self.newSpecificationTitleTextField!.text)
  data?.setValue("\(self.specs)", forKey: "NomeScenario")
        data?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true) //Write data to file permanently

    }))
```